# Problem with passing parameters to Jenkins build using Jenkins Job Builder

Tags: java, jenkins, yaml, multibranch-pipeline, jenkins-job-builder

I want to pass custom parameters to my Jenkins builds using [Jenkins Job Builder](https://jenkins-job-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

**My current job definition YAML file and configuration file look like this:**

`deploy.yaml`

```
- job:
    name: 'TestJobName'
    display-name: 'TestJobName'
    description: 'TestJobName multibranch job'
    folder: TestFolder
    script-path: Jenkinsfile
    project-type: multibranch
    disabled: false
    scm:
      - git:
          url: '<my_private_repo_link>'
          credentials-id: github
          submodule:
            disable: false
            recursive: true
            parent-credentials: true
          discover-branches: true
          ignore-on-push-notifications: false
          discover-tags: false
          build-strategies:
            - skip-initial-build: true
          clean:
            after: true
            before: true
          prune: true
          shallow-clone: true
          use-author: true
          wipe-workspace: true
          property-strategies:
            all-branches:
                - suppress-scm-triggering: true
```

`jenkins_jobs.ini`

```
[job_builder]
ignore_cache=True
keep_descriptions=False
include_path=.:scripts:~/git/
recursive=False
exclude=.*:manual:./development
allow_duplicates=False
update=all

[jenkins]
user=<my_username>
password=<my_password>
url=http://localhost:8080
query_plugins_info=False
```

**And it works perfectly fine:**

`$ jenkins-jobs --conf jenkins_jobs.ini update deploy.yaml`

```
INFO:jenkins_jobs.cli.subcommand.update:Updating jobs in ['deploy.yaml'] ([])
INFO:jenkins_jobs.builder:Number of jobs generated:  1
INFO:jenkins_jobs.builder:Creating jenkins job TestFolder/TestJobName
INFO:jenkins_jobs.cli.subcommand.update:Number of jobs updated: 1
INFO:jenkins_jobs.builder:Number of views generated:  0
INFO:jenkins_jobs.cli.subcommand.update:Number of views updated: 0
```

**However, if i add *parameters* block right from [documentation](https://jenkins-job-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameters.html):**

```
  parameters:
    - string:
        name: FOO
        default: bar
        description: "A parameter named FOO, defaults to 'bar'."
```

**I get this:**

[image]

**With this error message:**

```
jenkins.JenkinsException: Error in request. Possibly authentication failed [500]: Server Error
```

**In Jenkins logs i can see more explanatory error message:**

```
WARNING h.i.i.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler#handleException: Caught unhandled exception with ID 38c914db-978c-469f-87a5-b12cb707efc2
java.lang.ClassCastException: hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty cannot be cast to com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.AbstractFolderProperty
        at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.AbstractFolder.getOverrides(AbstractFolder.java:678)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:281)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:281)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:694)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:763)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1633)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
        at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:76)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
        at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:561)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1612)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Looking for ideas on how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because of the `project-type` that you are using, the `multibranch` project type does not accept adding a parameter. Instead, what you can do is adding a parameter in your `Jenkinsfile`.
As a testing, I have added a parameter in a `job-template` for a `pipeline` project type, and it did work.

```
- project:
    name: my-project
    repo-project-name: my-bitbuket-project-name
    my-service-account: my_service_account_credential
    jenkins-file-path: .ci/Jenkinsfile
    jobs:
      - '{quality-pipeline}':
          repo-name: project-component-main
          jenkins-file-path: .ci/Jenkinsfile
          parameters_chosen:
            - script-verbosity
            - cleanup
          jenkinsfile-path: .ci/JenkinsfileQuality
          trigger-defined: '0 0 * * *'
          branch-var: 'RUN_ON_MASTER_BRANCH'

- job-template:
    name: '{quality-pipeline}'
    project-type: pipeline
    parameters: '{obj:parameters_chosen}'
    triggers:
      - timed: '{trigger-defined}'
    pipeline-scm:
      scm:
        - git:
            url: 'https://bitbucket.foo-bar.com/scm/{repo-project-name}/{repo-name}.git'
            credentials-id: '{my-service-account}'
            branches:
              - '{branch-var}'
      script-path: '{jenkinsfile-path}'

# Shared Parameters
- parameter:
    name: script-verbosity
    parameters:
      - choice:
          name: VERBOSITY
          choices:
            - INFO
            - DEBUG
          description: 'Verbosity level.'

- parameter:
    name: cleanup
    parameters:
      - bool:
          name: CLEANUP
          default: true
          description: 'Cleanup workspace'
```